# Missing Visual Studio 2010 toolbox items in ASP.NET Website or Web Application?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, toolbox

After installing Visual Studio Professional 2010, and creating a new website or web application, toolbox items are missing!
I've tried also running Visual Studio in safe mode "devenv.exe /SafeMode", I got the same issue.
I also tried reset toolbox items, and nothing happened.

FYI: I've installed set of visual studio extensions.

Any way to resolve that issue.

Comment: Try running `devenv /ResetSettings`

Comment: @JonH: still getting the same issue after trying devenv /ResetSettings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this from Edwer Fang from the MSDN:
Hello,

Do you mean you are not able to see toolbox or items in toolbox? What is the version of your VS2010?

You can take the following steps to see if they help:

a)     Try to run devenv /ResetSettings (in command prompt), devenv /setup, and devenv /resetskippkgs, devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates to eliminate the related potential problem.

b)     Try disabling Add-ins (e.g. “Tools” | “Add-in Manager”) or run “devenv.exe /SafeMode”.This can eliminate the possibility that third party Add-ins or packages are causing problems. (For more detailed VS command line switches information, see: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx )

c)     Try creating a new project. Sometimes corrupted project settings can cause problems. These are project specific.

d)     Try to reboot the operating system to safe mode. This can help to isolate whether any other applications are interfering with Visual Studio. Note that some features (like IIS) are not available under safe mode. Please check whether this can be applied or not. In addition to safe mode, we can also try “clean boot”: How to configure Windows XP to start in a "clean boot" state http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310353 .

e)      Try to create a new user account. This can help isolate user profile corruption related causes.

If they all not help, I suggest you repair your Visual Studio to have it worked.

Please remember to mark the replies as answers if they help and unmark them if they provide no help

Source:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vstsstart/thread/2b924ed5-e49c-4ca7-acb0-a3b18ce0d0bc

Comment: I cannot see items in toolbox.

Comment: @Ahmed - Sorry I don't have many more ideas besides a fresh install.Are you sure you didn't simply close out of it or unpinned it.  Check the view settings in VS.

Comment: @JonH Thank you so much! I was looking for that for a long time! devenv /resetskippkgs worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Tools > Import and Export settings` menu to reset all environment settings, you just need to use the appropriate collection setting.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Tools > Import and Export settings" menu to reset all environment settings :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools menu
        Imports and exports
           Reset all environment setting
                follow the steps
                  finish
You can find the DATA tab in the tool box