# In Visual Studio 2012 wpf toolbox the "common xaml contols" are disable to use

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, gridview, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and developing wpf application and i need to use grid view control .I search grid view by :right clicking toolbox -> choose items ->in tab WPF Components  .But it is present and already checked in adjacent tab "Windows XAMAL component". After closing that i right clicked on toolbox -> clicked Show All .That showed me all hidden control tabs in toolbox .So i found grid view in Common XAML Control Tab but it is disabled for use and can't be dragged on wpf form .Can any body tell me how i can use grid view in wpf form ?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Though,I see this question is too old.

But still i would like to redirect the searchers towards the Solutions so far possible in this following link.

[Visual Studio 2010 toolbox controls disabled or inactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871531/visual-studio-2010-toolbox-controls-disabled-or-inactive/25237420#25237420)

Excerpt here :

1. Reset Toolbar
2. Delete .tbd files from C:\Users(your
   user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
3. Go to Cmd > devenv.exe /SafeMode & devenv.exe /ResetSettings

Hope this helps.!

.