# Reason for toolbox items being greyed out

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, toolbox

I would like to know if I can get the reason for toolbox items being greyed out.
I have some of them, and I would like to know the exact reason for being greyed out since I don't understand the reason in some situations.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8871531/1070452

Comment: Yeah, it is. Can you make your comment the answer, please?