# vb.net 2017 all toolbox tools are greyed out

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, visual-studio

In VB.NET 2017 PRO, for my Windows app project,
Toolbox  >  Common Controls were enabled, and dragged to form OK.
But Standard controls were dimmed, and I needed Drop Down List.
I did:   right-click Toolbox  >  Reset

..now ALL controls are dimmed, and I'm dead-in-the-water.

Comment: Have you tried a new project? Have you repaired VS? - the installer to do so is likely to be in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe".

Answer (score 2):

'Busse' suggestions did not work.

I at least got the default tools re-enabled:
1. Restarted Windows...  no effect
2. Restarted VB.NET ...  no effect
3. Closed solution and opened new VB Windows app project...  default tools restored!
4. Closed this new solution, and re-opened my original project...  default tools are back!

Comment: Sorry! Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I've lost access to my toolbox in two situations (one being considerably more obvious and silly than the other):

1. Application is presently running (debugging)
2. I changed the target framework under the Application Tab (It was NET Framework 4 Client... changed it to 4.5.2) under My Project.

Option one is probably not the issue, but should it be - just stop debugging.  For Option 2, the only result that was successful for me was closing everything and re-creating the application from scratch.  Hopefully it is not either of those for you, but I wanted to at least point them out.

Answer (score 0):

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871531/visual-studio-2010-toolbox-controls-disabled-or-inactive) is about 2010 but it seems to be the same issue (not that there was anything definitive, there were a lot of things that people said worked for them).

One of the things that was in there that I would try since you said you already did a reset on the tool box is to add a new tab. Right click, select Add Tab, give it a name. Then once added, reset the toolbox again.